# Include a delete and edit button in a for each statement to output rows from a database in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

Trying to include a delete and edit button in a for each statement to output rows from a database. All my code for the for each works so that it outputs the values from the database but i can't figure out how to incorporate a button which shows with every tuple. Any help would be awesome! My current code looks like:

```
try {
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if (!$results) { // check we have some results
            echo "No trainingCourses found <br />";
        } else { //generate table of trainingCourses
            print "<table>\n";
            echo "<th>Meeting ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Date</th><th>Link</th>\n";
            foreach ($results as $row) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["trainingID"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["title"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["date"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["link"] . "</td>";

                echo "</tr>\n";
            }
            print "</table>\n";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    //$conn->rollBack();
    // If something raised an exception in our transaction block of statements,
    // roll back any work performed in the transaction
    exit('<p>Unable to complete transaction!</p>'.$e->getMessage());
     }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Be careful about showing the real exception message to your users.  It often contains database credentials.

Comment: What have you tried until now? You should be able to output the basic button on yourself?

Comment: thanks for the tip! Its just there for now so i can see the error message ill remove it when the site goes live!

Comment: This is really my first attempt, im pretty new to php so I wasn't really sure on the best way to do it as its within the foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["trainingID"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["title"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["date"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["link"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='linktodelete.php?id=".$row['trainingID']."'>delete</a></td>";
                echo "</tr>\n";
            }
```

I just added it as a link, but it should give you an idea of how to change it to a button. You would want to make sure you add another th to the header row so the number of columns matches.

Comment: Seems so obvious now! Thank you!

Comment: with this method how do I send the value of "trainingID" to the corresponding page the button redirects to?

Answer (score 0):

This will output buttons on each row:

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["trainingID"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["title"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["date"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["link"] . "</td>";
    echo '<td><button type="button" name="edit">Edit</button></td>';
    echo '<td><button type="button" name="delete">Delete</button></td>';
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

You'd need to change the title to account for the extra columns:

```
echo '<th>Meeting ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Date</th><th>Link</th><th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>\n';
```